# Trouble getting StreamingReader to work with Excel xlsx Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

This is the code that I have for reading a very large excel file (xlsx) that is 23.5MB with 700,000+ rows.

```
String dir = rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles" + File.separator 
+ FILE_NAME;
File fisNew = new File(dir);
Workbook w = StreamingReader.builder()
.rowCacheSize(100)
.open(fisNew);
Sheet worksheet = null;
worksheet = w.getSheetAt(0);
worksheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
```

I get an `UnsupportedOperationException` Null pointer error on this line:
`worksheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();` And I also don't get an actual String value when I print out this line: `SpecialtyUtil.removeWhiteSpaces(excelheader.getCell(0))`. I am supposed to get the name of the column but I get some `StreamingSheet` string instead. Not so sure what I need to change here in order to process a xlsx file.

EDIT: Any idea how to write to an excel file using StreamingReader? I know that it is an unsupported operation, but is there a workaround?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using and what is the version of Apache Poi ?

Comment: if you shrink your excel to only one row, still this error?

Comment: I am using jdk8 and apache poi 4.1.0 and xlsx-streamer 2.1.0

Comment: You mean if I change rowCacheSize(100) to rowCacheSize(1)? Yes I still get the same error. If getRow() is an unsupported method, then what would I use instead?

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the following source code in github link, StreamingSheet does not support the method getPhysicalNumberOfCells(). I provide below the code snippet.

```
/**
   * Not supported
   */
  @Override
  public int getPhysicalNumberOfRows() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
```

github link is given below.
https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingSheet.java#L97

Comment: Okay, so what would I use to replace this then? That's where I'm stuck at. I need to get the rows but not sure of a workaround?

Comment: Check this useful links. https://howtodoinjava.com/library/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/ . http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html

Comment: I started using XSSF however, the file that I was processing was too large and would cause a GCOverhead Limit Exceeded error, even after adding the following options to my Tomcat run configurations: -Xmx1024m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit. So I started to use the StreamingReader to only store 100 rows in memory instead of loading everything, but I am stuck at this UnsupportedOperation null exception.

Comment: Can you provide the link of your excel sheet if it is possible, I can try to look into it.

Comment: I am not so sure how to attach the file or upload it anywhere? Could I have a link to your github and I can attach the file that way?

Comment: You can create a github account and upload the excel sheet and you can share the link so that people will help you.

Comment: with streaming apis, like excel-streaming-reader, you need to read the whole sheet - for physical row count, would it be feasible to just iterate through the rows in the sheet and get the row num of the last row? For cell count in a given row, latest excel-streaming-reader code supports that: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingRow.java#L107

Comment: Any idea how to write to an excel file using StreamingReader? I know that it is an unsupported operation, but is there a workaround?

Comment: @Vicky1940, I have got a similar problem from another user also, I am also trying to do something. Due to other works, I am unable to complete it. I am trying to achieve, once it is done, I will definitely let you know.

Comment: Okay, I was able to read the file but now I am unable to use the write function because it is an unsupported method but I'm trying to figure out a workaround

Answer (score 0):

We can use getLastRowNum()

```
Integer noOfCol = sheet.getLastRowNum(); // row no starts from 0 --- n
```

here is the implementation

```
@Override
public int getLastRowNum() {
  return reader.getLastRowNum();
}
```

[StreamingSheet.java](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingSheet.java#L127)